# Wordpress Jquery Plugins

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I was wondering can Jquery WordPress Plugins be used on normal sites? I know this probably sounds like the noobist question ever but just looking at some plugins but they say WordPress plugin in the title I was wondering whats the big difference, why add Wordpress in the title if it works on normal html sites...

Thanks for anyone that can spare the time to answer my noob question. :)

Comment: Can you use the bus wheel on normal sedan car? This sounds like the noobist mechanical question, but looking at some bus wheels - they look like a general wheel (they both are black and round). Wondering what's the big difference. Why use bus wheels on the buses if it may be used with normal cars as well?

Answer (score 0):

Those plugins will be designed to work with the Wordpress plugin architecture - so they won't work outside of this.

To use jQuery on a non wordpress site just add this line to your page `<head>`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And you're ready to start using jQuery in your pages.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugins run on normal website can use on WordPress site. **But the reverse is difficult** unless you edit the core files.

An example to show is [**jQuery Nivo Slider**](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/pricing/). They have both WordPress and normal version. If you have basic knowledge in html and knows the structure of WordPress, then you can run the normal version on WordPress website.

But people love less efforts. So if you use the WordPress plugin version, there is no need of knowing HTML or WordPress structures. You can customize the plugin from the admin interface.

Also WordPress plugin options are saving in WordPress database. So these things will not work on a normal website..

So simply **Car wheels will not work on bus**!!! [thanks @zerkms for great example :) ]

Comment: so basically let me get this right if its a WP JQuery Plugin it will be really hard to get it to work on a normal website, unless I can go in an extensively edit the plugin.